# unable to check which drawable image is present in Imageview

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have made an Imageview which contain drawable vector image and I want check which drawable image is present in Imageview but after trying many conditions unable to check which drawable is present in ImageView, I have try this

```
addbookimg.drawable.constantState == 
this.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_a_photo_24,this.theme).constantState
```

and also tried this

```
addbookimg.drawable.constantState == 
this.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_a_photo_24).constantState
```